# Failed to start iOS Simulator in the mac

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms project.

I'm using vs2015.

Today I updated Xamarin to the latest version:4.0.0.1697.

When I tried to connet my mac as the Xamarin Mac Agent, vs shows the message below:

**Starting Agent Build 4.0.0.1697...**

**Failed to start iOS Simulator in the mac**

**An error occured starting the Build 4.0.0.1697 agent: The operation has timed out.**

**Starting Agent Designer 4.0.0.1697...**

**An error occured starting the Designer 4.0.0.1697 agent: The operation has timed out.**

**The Xamarin Mac Agent could not be fully started. Agents not started: IDB 4.0.0.1697, Designer 4.0.0.1697, Build 4.0.0.1697. Please check the logs for more details.**

So I can't debug the ios app.

I don't know how to do next.

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:14.7579] MacServer State transition from SshConnectingState to SshConnectedState on 192.168.0.207 (192.168.0.207)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:14.7659] MacServer State transition from SshConnectedState to AgentsStartingState on 192.168.0.207 (192.168.0.207)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:14.7799] Starting agents on Mac 192.168.0.207 (192.168.0.207)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:14.7959] Activating the Mac...
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:18.6192] Starting Agent IDB 4.0.0.1697...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:18.6292] MacServer State transition from AgentsStartingState to LimitedState on 192.168.0.207 (192.168.0.207)
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.Messaging.State.ServerStateContext Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:18.6352] Connected to the Mac 192.168.0.207 (192.168.0.207) with Limited support.
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer Error: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:29.3798] An error occured starting the IDB 4.0.0.1697 agent: The operation has timed out.

System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.Ssh.AgentCommands.StartAgent(AgentInfo agent, Int32 port, Int32 timeout, Boolean debugMode, String[] extraArgs)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService.StartAgent(AgentInfo agentInfo, Boolean restartAutomatically)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer.StartAgent(AgentInfo agentInfo) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\2511\deffc901\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio.IOS\Messaging\MacServer.cs:line 366
Xamarin.Messaging.VisualStudio.MessagingService Information: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:29.9288] Starting Agent Build 4.0.0.1697...
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.MacServer Error: 0 : [2015-12-07 18:06:31.4349] An error occured starting the Build 4.0.0.1697 agent: Xamarin Information: 0 : Xamarin - 4.0.0.1697-cycle6-baseline+deffc90
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner Information: 0 : Starting Build 4.0.0.1697...
Xamarin.Messaging.Build.BuildAgent Information: 0 : Starting Agent: Build 4.0.0.1697
Xamarin.Messaging.Build.BuildAgent Information: 0 : Build 4.0.0.1697 agent started
Failed-The classes in the module cannot be loaded.


Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingException: Xamarin Information: 0 : Xamarin - 4.0.0.1697-cycle6-baseline+deffc90
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.AgentConsoleRunner Information: 0 : Starting Build 4.0.0.1697...
Xamarin.Messaging.Build.BuildAgent Information: 0 : Starting Agent: Build 4.0.0.1697
Xamarin.Messaging.Build.BuildAgent Information: 0 : Build 4.0.0.1697 agent started
Failed-The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
```

Comment: Did you check the logs? What did they say?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using, and what happens when you clean the solution and then debug?

Comment: I added some error information.

Comment: Same problem. VS2015 up to date. All xamarin versions up to date. All mac up to date. All Windows up to date.

Comment: Cleaned / rebuilt / deleted xamarin cache. It deployed only once correctly. ps -eax Xamarin shows that a process is stuck (ie: it does not finish) : /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch --launchsim /Users/ypeg/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AppIos/b10d24617dbae8c4e83ea1c55ba90b1c/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/AppIos.app --device=:v2:udid=62CEF7C6-DE24-4AC8-958E-1B0C48A6969E -stdout .../out.log -stderr .../err.log -argument=-connection-mode -argument=none --sdkroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer -sdk 9.2

Comment: You can find the logs here : Help > Xamarin > Open Logs

Comment: Could be an issue with on of the Visual Studio extensions that you installed or that was automatically installed for you. I ran into [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=47263) one the other day, but I do not think yours is the same as that. But you might try updating all VS extensions and making sure you are running VS2015 Update 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by updated Xamarin.iOS version same as the Visual Studio of.
Then I succeed to run my App in the Mac.
Thank all the people focused my question.

Answer (score 3):

So I ran into this problem. It was driving me nuts.

My problem was that I was using the Mac just to be able to launch the app. Otherwise, it was just sitting idle. What turned out to be the problem was that the 'Energy Saver' settings on my mac was set with "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" checked. That was the reason for the failure in my case. 
It is also probably better to check 'Wake for network access'.

Answer (score 0):

I constantly have issues with Xamarin Mac Agent and Visual Studio running on Parallels (Currently why i'm here). However, **sometimes** following the troubleshooting steps in this guide helps, however, not always.

I suspect my issue lies deeper - yours could possibly aid from this link.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/xamarin-mac-agent/xma-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone stumbles on this there are a couple things to try.

There are of course the three R's Restart Reboot and Reinstall.

Restart Visual Studio and xcode.
Reboot all pc's involved, The Build agents sometimes get into funky states and rebooting clears them all out and lets you start fresh
For good measure reboot your router while your at it and make sure your IP addresses are what you assume they are.

Then Update\Reinstall. If the xcode on your mac got updated you may need an Xamarin update in VS in order to make the connection or Xamarin Studio Update on the Mac.

Open all three
Xcode, Xamarin Studio on the Mac and VisualStudio 
and make sure all 3 are updated.
While your in Xcode go ahead and create a new project and run it. See if the simulator comes up from within XCode or if you get prompts to accept licenses etc.

It may be necessary to reinstall Xcode if the update doesn't fix it or doesn't update.

After all that if it still doesn't work you can put your toes in the water and your A$$3 in the sand with a PBR on a beach in Mexico. That fixes everything.